# Flutter fl_chart limit amount of titles on x axis

Tags: flutter, dart, fl-chart

Is it possible to limit the amount of shown titles on the x axis (e.g. max 3 titles) to avoid that titles overlap like in the picture?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bottomTitles` parameter when creating your `LineChartData` object to specify an interval.

```
bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
    sideTitles: SideTitles(
        showTitles: true,
        interval: 10,
    ),
),
```

If you want even more control, you can specify a functor for the `getTitlesWidget` parameter to control exactly which values are labeled and how they're styled.

Take a look at the code sample for `Sample 1` [here](https://github.com/imaNNeo/fl_chart/blob/master/repo_files/documentations/line_chart.md#sample-1-source-code).